# Connect on website with HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest, webclient

I tried to use HttpWebRequest to connect on a site to download a source which necessited to be loged. The request don't connect me or don't keep me connected to permit me to do what I want like downoad the source to get special informations linked to my account for example.

Here is my first try :

```
private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("example.com/index.php?do=login");
        CookieContainer cookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
        request.CookieContainer = cookieContainer;

        request.Method = "POST";
        string postData = "username=user&password=pass";
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
        request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        request.UserAgent = "Foo";
        request.Accept = "*/*";
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Basic ");
        request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
        dataStream.Close();
        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        string Text = "";

        foreach (Cookie cook in response.Cookies)
        {
            Text += "COOKIE: " + cook.Name + " = " + cook.Value + "\r\n";
        }
        request.AllowAutoRedirect = true;
        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();

        webBrowser1.Navigate("example.com/client.php"); // client.php can be only visited when the user is log in.
        // redirect me on /index.php instead of client.php
    }
```

I also tried to use webclient :

```
using (var client = new CookieAwareWebClient())
        {
            var values = new NameValueCollection
          {
                { "username", "user" },
                { "password", "pass" },
          };

            // Was forced to use user-agent or the server return me a 403 Error
            client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
            client.UploadValues("example.com/index.php?process=login", values);

            client.Headers.Add("user-agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.2; .NET CLR 1.0.3705;)");
            string result = client.DownloadString("example.com/client.php");
            Console.WriteLine(result);
            // The source is a document location replace to logout.php?raison=Erreur
        }

private class CookieAwareWebClient : WebClient
    {
        public CookieAwareWebClient()
            : this(new CookieContainer())
        { }
        public CookieAwareWebClient(CookieContainer c)
        {
            this.CookieContainer = c;
        }
        public CookieContainer CookieContainer { get; set; }

        protected override WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri address)
        {
            WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(address);

            var castRequest = request as HttpWebRequest;
            if (castRequest != null)
            {
                castRequest.CookieContainer = this.CookieContainer;
            }
            return request;
        }
    }
```

I'm a beginner so I'm sure I did stupid mistakes but I search to solve my probem since 2 weeks, I really hope someone can help me.

Sorry for the English, I'm French.

Comment: Your two samples reference different final URLs.  The webclient-based sample returns the authenticated page me if you query `http://bobbalive.fr/me.php` rather than `http://bobbalive.fr/client.php`

Comment: **Main post Edited** : I replaced me.php by client.php on the example but they both redirect the user on /index.php if he is not connected. I just used the webclient to see if the connection was a succes or not (actually not).

Comment: WebBrowser control just uses IE as far as I know; I don't think it has any method to adding cookies into it just like that. Is your goal to show a logged in screen, or to scrape the HTML content of the site after logging in? In the second case you don't need that WebBrowser control.